# Calculate sum of 2 numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, input, console-application

I want to write code that calculate sum of 2 number. My main problem I can not enter two numbers in a row. When I enter first number program duplicate it and stop working. For my plan programm should work until second number and then stop.
Here is my code:

```
namespace test;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers to calculate or tap ENTER to exit");
        string enter = Console.ReadLine();
        while(true){
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(enter);
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(enter);
            if(x > 0 && y > 0){
                int z = x + y;
                Console.WriteLine(z);
                break;
            }else if(enter == ""){
                break;
            }else{
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid option");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried writing x outside "when", but did not work. I also tried to run this code without "If" but I can't. I just want to enter 2 number in a row.

Comment: You are calling `Console.ReadLine()` only once. Therefore, you get only one user entry. `int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: Did you want to enter the numbers with a space between them? Like `7 13`? Please be more specific on what inputs you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because you only use `Console.ReadLine()` once and then you use that value both for the x and y.

Instead you should do something like that:

```
namespace test;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers to calculate or tap ENTER to exit");
        string enter;
        while(true){
            enter = Console.ReadLine();
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(enter);
            enter = Console.ReadLine();
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(enter);
            if(x > 0 && y > 0){
                int z = x + y;
                Console.WriteLine(z);
                break;
            }else if(enter == ""){
                break;
            }else{
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid option");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers to calculate or tap ENTER to exit");
        string enter1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string enter2 = Console.ReadLine();
        while (true)
        {
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(enter1);
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(enter2);
            if (x > 0 && y > 0)
            {
                int z = x + y;
                Console.WriteLine(z);
                break;
            }
            else if (enter1 == "" || enter2 == "")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid option");
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below, as `Console.ReadLine()` will give a string.

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(enter.Split()[0]);
int y = Convert.ToInt32(enter.Split()[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

You don't need a while loop in this case. because you just need to take two inputs from the user, and then calculate the sum and exit.

You are using the same `enter` variable for your calculation. instead, you should read two times and store two variables.

As a suggestion, you can use [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-7.0) to convert the string to int. it provides you flexibility if the given string is not convertible to int. you can check its return value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can loop until a positive number is entered for each of the two numbers.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of two numbers.");
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        while (!AskForNumber("Enter the first number:", out x) || x < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
        }
        while (!AskForNumber("Enter second number:", out y) || y < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
        }
        int sum = x + y;
        Console.WriteLine($"{x}+{y} = {sum}");
    }

    static bool AskForNumber(string prompt, out int number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        return int.TryParse(input, out number);
    }
}
```

Example output

> ```text
> Sum of two numbers.
> Enter the first number:
>
> Invalid input.
> Enter the first number:
> ALSDJD
> Invalid input.
> Enter the first number:
> 7
> Enter second number:
> -3
> Invalid input.
> Enter second number:
> 3
> 7+3 = 10
> ```

The function `AskForNumber()` prompts the user for a number and returns true if the input *can* be parsed into a number, or false otherwise. The actual numeric value is assigned to an `out` parameter named `number`.

The main function, has two loops, one for each input. Each loop not only checks if the input is valid, but also the inputs are non-negative (the or `x<0`) condition. Once a valid number is set the program moves on.

PS.

In your question, the main `while(true)` loop serves no purpose because *all* the branches of the `if` statement inside result in a `break;` which exists in the loop. You should make one a `continue;` in order for the loop to loop back and try again.